# С SSL сайт медленно работает

Tags: http, https, ssl

Добрый день. У меня есть сайт и страницы по https грузятся медленнее (на 2-3 секунды) чем без SSL (по http)

Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли браузера на что больше всего уходит времени

Comment: Пишет, то сама страница все время занимает. Вот страница https://apsipirk.savgroup.ru/mobilieji-telefonai/

Comment: это сайт автоматически переключает на https. каким образом вы открывает его без https?

Comment: Вот нашел решение. Указал в качестве домена сайта не https://site.ru а //site.ru

Результат - все стало быстро открываться. Может кому пригодится моё решение.

Comment: Оформите ваш комментарии в виде ответа и примите его

Answer (score 2):

Вот нашел решение. Указал в качестве домена сайта не site.ru а //site.ru Результат - все стало быстро открываться. Может кому пригодится моё решение.

Comment: Интересно, почему так?